# How to subscribe a razor component to an external C# event

Tags: maui-blazor

This question is within the context of .NET MAUI Blazor Hybrid, which is referencing a pure C# Class Library as one of its dependencies.

The C# Class Library is self contained and contains its own async code and events. Within the MAUI app I start some async code within the C# Class Library, which goes on to run different tasks in the background. The C# library has different EventHandlers that are triggered when various events occur in the background.

I have a razor component called SomeComponent.razor -> How do I make this component re-render when some external event occurs within the C# Class Library? Conceptually I'd essentially like to "subscribe" SomeComponent.razor to an EventHandler (ie: anExternalEventHandler += SomeComponent.razor) purely so that the .razor file will re-render any time the associated event is invoked (I hope my intention makes sense).

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to the [ASP.NET Core Razor component rendering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/rendering?source=recommendations&view=aspnetcore-7.0#receiving-a-call-from-something-external-to-the-blazor-rendering-and-event-handling-system). This article mentions the `StateHasChanged` method to manually trigger a component to render.

```
 private void OnTimerCallback()
    {
        _ = InvokeAsync(() =>
        {
            currentCount++;
            StateHasChanged();
        });
    }
```

[Receiving a call from something external to the Blazor rendering and event handling system](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/rendering?source=recommendations&view=aspnetcore-7.0#receiving-a-call-from-something-external-to-the-blazor-rendering-and-event-handling-system) this is more relevant to your situation.

Comment: Indeed I can confirm this works - I can subscribe to a regular C# event within OnInitialized, the subscriber is simply a callback method within the @code section that does the InvokeAsync of the StateHasChanged. Thanks